# How can I get a joined value in sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

joined column come out like this (the last one - 'Perfume.name'). 
How can I get this in Thunk??

```
  {
    id: 1,
    male: '50',
    female: '50',
    value: '70',
    useYn: 'Y',
    createdAt: 2021-12-05T18:55:34.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-12-05T18:55:34.000Z,
    'Perfume.name': 'Eros'
  },
```

It doesn't work like item.Perfume.name...

help me out
thank you

Comment: Can you show the whole Sequelize query, please?